# Regular expression not matching specific string and strict test

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression:

- a string of characters containing 0-9
- length between 4 and 6
- cannot be the string: 0000

I have: `^[0-9]{4,6}$`  but it is missing 0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, I decided to answer this one as it is an interesting question although it's in a language I do not understand. Not giving you +1 because of question language. Will upvote you on a fix.

try this one:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{3,5}$
```

This will guarantee first digit is non-zero. If you want any digit to be non-zero the maybe something like this:

```
^([1-9]|[0-9](?=[0-9]{0,4}[1-9]))[0-9]{3,5}$
```

update - simpler one:

```
^(?=[0-9]{0,5}[1-9])[0-9]{4,6}$
```